# Getting "This field is required" error even though I set null=True and blank=True

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a `Post` model for users submitting posts. I've given the `content` field of `Post` an attribute of `blank=True`. But for some reason django tells me `content` is still required. `form_post.errors` prints this:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>content<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Here's my code:

**models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=76)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='1')
```

**forms**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget)
    title = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'title'})

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'category',
            'image',
            'id',
            'user'
        ]
```

**views**

```
def post(request):
    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            print('valid')
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user

            category = form_post.cleaned_data['category']
            for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
                if a == category:
                    category = b
                    form_post.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/%s' % category)
        else:
            print(form_post.errors)
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'allauth_login': allauth_login,
            'allauth_signup': allauth_signup,
            'form_post': form_post
        }

        return render(request, 'post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

**html**

```
...
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="submitContainer">
    <div class="article_title_div">
     {{ form_post.title|add_class:"article_title" }}
     </div>
    <div>
    </div>
        {{ form_post.category }}
    </div>
    <div class="submitButton">
        <button class="submitArticleSubmit" type="submit">Post</button>
</div>
</form>
...
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: You have `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` after setting `blank=True` and `null=True`, haven't you?

Comment: Yes I've done both of them

Comment: That's because you're overriding the `content` inside your `PostForm` (`content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget)`. Put a `required=False` inside it.

Comment: Thanks that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this, is because you're [`overriding the default model field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields). Both `content` and `title`.

Although, `content` can be nullable when stored in your database, it is `required` by your form (`content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget)`).

Change to `content = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget, required=False)` to make it optional on form submission.